# Android send data to JavaScript methods

Tags: javascript, android

How do I send data to JavaScript methods/functions?

I saw toast examples with javascriptInterface, but I am unable to relate it to my scenario.

My JavaScript function:

```
function printInfo() {

    var request = new AudioFileRequest('1.wav');
    request.send();
}
```

I want to record the sound in mobile and send that sound file to the method **"AudioFileRequest"**.

Comment: So you want to call js-function from java code, right?

Comment: i want to send data from java code to javascript method

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you already loaded a file with the `printInfo` function to a web view.
To execute some JavaScript code from the Java side you may load a JavaScript function, for example:

```
String data = "1.wav";
webview.loadUrl("javascript:printInfo('" + data + "')");
```

And your JavaScript function is:

```
function printInfo(fileName) {
    var request = new AudioFileRequest(fileName);
    request.send();
}
```